# How to efficiently filter wildcard in a list using glob

Tags: python, glob

Assume I have a list of files

```
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S1/pre/dr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S10/pre/dr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S11/pre/dr_zer.pkl'

'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S1/pre/ec_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S10/pre/ec_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S11/pre/ec_zer.pkl'

'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S1/pre/rr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S10/pre/rr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S11/pre/rr_zer.pkl'
```

I would like to extract only the filename `dr_zer.pkl` and `ec_zer.pkl`.

Such that the output are as below

```
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S1/pre/dr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S10/pre/dr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S11/pre/dr_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S1/pre/ec_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S10/pre/ec_zer.pkl'
'/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/S11/pre/ec_zer.pkl'
```

Currently, the code below should do the work

```
main_outer='/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/*/*/'
event_type = ['ec', 'dr']
all_path=[glob.glob(f"{main_outer}*/{event_type_}_zer.pkl") for event_type_ in event_type]
```

But I wonder, whether the `glob` can be simplified as below

```
all_path = glob.glob(f"{main_outer}*/{'ec' |'dr'}_zer.pkl")
```

or something similar

Comment: Walking the filesystem is going to be the more expensive part. Use a flexible glob and then filter the results returned using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

> No tilde expansion is done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be correctly matched.

Since you said "efficient," you want to avoid listing the directory twice and using temp memory for paths you're not interested in, so do

```
main_outer = '/mnt/d/data_set/droota/al/*/*/'
all_paths = [
    path for path in glob.iglob(f"{main_outer}*/*_zer.pkl")
    if path.endswith("ec_zer.pkl") or path.endswith("dr_zer.pkl")
]
```